# Software Load Balancer for android

Tags: internet, samsung-galaxy-note-2, 4g

i have H+ data network from my mobile phone network operator and 2Mb connection with Wi-Fi router connected to the DSL  in home.
i want to Combine this two in my android device (galaxy note II ) for faster and more reliable Internet.
is there any software that do it for me?

Comment: I assume you have a Wi-Fi router connected to the DSL?

Comment: @MatthewRead yes of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an app called "Super Download" that seems to be what you're looking for. From the XDA page:

> **DESCRIPTION**:
>
> Download web files much faster by using wifi and mobile data at the same time! 
>   Share or open a link from any program, like the web browser, and download it at speeds up to two times faster than usual.
>   This is the only tool that can download using wifi and mobile data connection simultaneously*!

It's a paid app on [Play Store,](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.opbyte.superdownload) but free on [XDA.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1667025)